# What is the best practice for navigating webpages back and forth while scraping it? (Selenium Python)

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I'm new to the topic and needed help on this problem.

Let's say the website that I'm trying to scrape has this structure:

```
...

<div class="product">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/product/1.html>
        <span class="p-name">Product One</span>
        <span class="p-price">$2.00</span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="product">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/product/2.html>
        <span class="p-name">Product Two</span>
        <span class="p-price">$32.00</span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="product">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/product/3.html>
        <span class="p-name">Product Three</span>
        <span class="p-price">$256.00</span>
    </a>
</div>

...
```

With those layout, I can get **Product Name** and **Product Price** easily. But let's say to get **Times Sold** and **Product Reviews**, I need to iterate through each product page to get those data. I know somehow I have to open a new tab or windows for each links but How do I accomplish this? Do I just start a new instance of the Web Driver? What is the best practice on this?

Thank you

Edit: Added My (Failed) Attempt

```
productList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product']")

for p in productList:
  pName = p.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='p-name']").text
  pPrice = p.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='p-price']").text

  p.click()

  # Grab Data from the new page here

  driver.back()
```

While this managed to get the Name, Price, and more data inside the Product Page, however after *driver.back()*, when trying to read the second Div, it throws and exception as below:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Comment: I would recommend parse all the product links first, store in some file and then parse through the products links to get the product details. Append all data later.

Comment: @ShahirAnsari the suggested solution is quite simple, I don't know why I didn't think of it! I guess I was expecting a more sophisticated solution. But I guess this works too. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is simple. Although the method you said about initializing a new instance would everytime to get product details also work but why complicate things.